# Does a symmetric operator on a Hilbert space have a symmetric adjoint?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose we have a linear operator $T$, densely-defined on some Hilbert space. If $T$ is symmetric (i.e., $T^*$ extends $T$: notationally, $T\subseteq T^*$) does it follow that $T^*$ is also symmetric (and therefore, in fact, self-adjoint)?

If so, where could I find a proof of this? If not, what is a counter-example showing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the differentiation operator, which is a classical example of a closed, densely-defined, symmetric, linear operator on the Hilbert Space which is not selfadjoint.

Specifically, let $X=L^{2}[0,1]$, and let $T=\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ on the domain $\mathcal{D}(T)$ consisting of all $f \in X$ such that $f$ is equal a.e. to an absolutely continuous $\tilde{f}$ on $[0,1]$ such that $\tilde{f}(0)=\tilde{f}(1)=0$. Then $T$ is symmetric with adjoint $T^{\star}$ equal to $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ on the domain $\mathcal{D}(T^{\star})$ consisting of all $f \in X$ such that $f$ is equal a.e. to an absolutely continuous function $\tilde{f}$ on $(0,1)$ for which $\int_{0}^{1}|\tilde{f}'|^{2}dx < \infty$.

You know that $T^{\star}$ is not symmetric because $e^{-x}\in\mathcal{D}(T^{\star})$ satisfies $T^{\star}e^{-x}=ie^{-x}$, and no symmetric operator can have an imaginary eigenvalue. Indeed, if $A$ is symmetric with $Af=\lambda f$, then
$(\lambda-\overline{\lambda})\|f\|^{2}=(Af,f)-(f,Af)=0$ implies $f=0$ or $\lambda$ is real.

One person asked about showing that $T^{\star}$ is as stated. Actually, it's very instructive to see how this works. So, let $T$ be as stated above, and let $V$ be $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ on the domain $\mathcal{D}(V)$ consisting of all absolutely continuous functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ with $f'\in L^{2}$. It's easy to verify that
$$    (Tf,g) = (f,Vg),\;\;\; f \in \mathcal{D}(T), g\in\mathcal{D}(V). $$
So, $T^{\star}$ extends or equals $V$, written as $V\preceq T^{\star}$. To show that $g \in \mathcal{D}(T^{\star})$ implies $g \in \mathcal{D}(V)$, assume that $g\in\mathcal{D}(T^{\star})$. Equivalently, there exists $m \in L^{2}$ such that
$$      (Tf,g) = (f,m),\;\;\; f \in \mathcal{D}(T). $$
Let $\chi_{[a,b]}$ the characteristic function of the interval $[a,b]$. We construct functions $f$ to use in the above:
$$       f_{a,h,b,k}(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\left(\frac{1}{h}\chi_{[a-h,a]}(t)-\frac{1}{k}\chi_{[b,b+k]}(t)\right)dt $$
For $0 \le a-h < a \le b < b+h \le 1$ this function is in $\mathcal{D}(T)$ with derivative equal a.e. to the integrand of the above integral. Plugging into the adjoint equation gives
$$     (Tf_{a,h,b,k},g)=-\frac{i}{h}\int_{a-h}^{a}\overline{g(t)}\,dt+\frac{i}{k}\int_{b}^{b+k}\overline{g(t)}\,dt = (f_{a,h,b,k},m)=\int_{0}^{1}f_{a,h,b,k}(t)\overline{m(t)}\,dt. $$
As $h \downarrow 0$  $f_{a,h,b,k}$ converges pointwise a.e. and remains bounded in doing so. The same thing is true as $k\downarrow 0$. So the left- and right- derivatives of $G(x)=\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt$ exists at all $x \in (0,1)$, and the two are equal as can be seen by the above. Furthermore, the derivative is continuous, with
$$     \left.\left[ \frac{d}{dx}i\int_{a}^{x}\overline{g(t)}dt\right]\right|_{a}^{b}
   = \int_{a}^{b}\overline{m(t)}\,dt,\;\;\; 0 < a \le b < 1. $$
However, the integral of $g$ is absolutely continuous. Therefore, the above derivative equals $\overline{g}$ a.e., which means that $g$ is equal a.e. to a continuous function $\tilde{g}$ and
$$
              -i\{ \tilde{g}(b)-\tilde{g}(a)\} = \int_{a}^{b}m(t)dt,\;\;\; 0 < a < b < 1.
$$
It follows that $\tilde{g}$ is absolutely continuous and $-i\tilde{g}'=m$ a.e.. By assumption $m\in L^{2}[0,1]$, which proves that $g \in \mathcal{D}(V)$ and $T^{\star}g=h=Vg$. Therefore $T^{\star}=V$, by domain and by action.

Comment: How would one prove that $\mathcal{D}(T^*)$ is given by your statement? Also I thought only self-adjoint operators need to have real eigen-values, not simply symmetric ones (we're only working with densely-defined operators).

Comment: @Stromael: Symmetric is enough to force real eigenvalues. The argument is probably very familiar to you: if $Tf=\lambda f$ and $T$ is symmetric, then $(\lambda-\overline{\lambda})(x,x)=(Tx,x)-(x,Tx)=0$ because of symmetry. For the second part, I am adding it to the post.

Answer (score 1):

If $T^*$ is symmetric then we would have that a symmetric linear operator $T$ is ad-joint,because $T^{**}=T$.

But this is false in general.

Check here when this can be true [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensions_of_symmetric_operators)

Comment: If $T\subseteq T^*\subseteq T^{**}$ then, taking the adjoint of the first extension relationship here, we have $T^* \supseteq T^{**}$, so in fact $T^*=T^{**}$. But I think in order for $T=T^{**}$ to hold we need that $T$ is closed, since $D(T)\subseteq D(T^*)$ implies that $T^*$ is densely defined, and for $T,T^*$ densely-defined we know that $\overline{T}=T^{**}$.

Comment: But I haven't solved anything. I just showed that your statement earlier only holds if $T$ is closed. And it requires the supposition that $T^*$ is symmetric, which I guess we can't just take as given...

Comment: @Stromael,i didn't see it clearly. i read it in a hurry 'cause i had to leave. Let $T : D(T)\to H$ be a symmetric operator with the property that $Ran(T) =H$. Then $T$ is self-adjoint. Find an operator with different Ran

Comment: Of course if $T$ is closed everything is easy

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't follow you. Why is a symmetric, surjective linear operator automatically self-adjoint? If $D(T)=H$ then it is clear, as $D(T^*)\subseteq H=D(T)$, so $D(T^*)=D(T)$. I don't see why $T=T^*$ is the case if $\text{Ran}(T)=H$.

Comment: @Stromael check theorem 1.10 http://people.math.gatech.edu/~loss/13Springtea/closedoperators.pdf

Comment: Very nice theorem and proof. Thank you very much.